# SAS: Data Step and additional row

Tags: optimization, dataset, sas

i have an data step.

```
   data One;
      set Two;
      /*some code*/
   run;
```

How to add additional row after last row of new table?

Is it possible to do optimal? (`One` table may have many rows ~ 100k - 10M)

Thanks!  ( it is `TOTAL` row, yes )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply appending the total line to your data set.

```
data one;
 set Two;
 /* some code * /
run;

data total;
 /* some code or use a proc to generate your totals */
run;

data final;
 set one total;
run;
```

will append the total row to the dataset one.

If you're generating summary lines / totals, I'd suggest you look into using `proc report`.  There's an option to output a dataset that has any summaries, groupings, etc that you create within the `report` procedure.  It can be a really powerful `proc`.

Something like this [SUGI Paper](http://support.sas.com/resources/papers/proceedings12/242-2012.pdf) might be useful to get you started.

*EDIT: based on the comments*

Summary for all:

```
 proc report data = sashelp.iris out=summary nowd;
   col species sepallength sepalwidth petallength petalwidth;

   rbreak after / summarize;
 run;
```

Summarize each species group and get total line

```
 proc report data = sashelp.iris out=summary nowd;
   col species sepallength sepalwidth petallength petalwidth;
   define species / group;
   rbreak after / summarize;
 run;
```

Comment: thanks! about optimal solution: is it good to do concantinating of these tables?

Comment: _However for those occasions when the SAS programming job either requires concatenation of a large number of datasets or concatenation of very large datasets (regardless of the number), the APPEND procedure is oftentimes a more sensible alternative_

This paper might help show when `proc append` is a better choice: http://www2.sas.com/proceedings/forum2008/085-2008.pdf

Comment: ok, when i create `One` table, i must `SUM` some fields. how can i use them later? (data set in data set? or what?)

Comment: Are you summing across the fields a) sum(field a, filed b) or b)taking the sum of all observations for a single field?

If a) use the sum() if b) use proc summary / means / sql.

With out some example data, it's hard to see what exactly you want to do.  Perhaps edit your original post?

Comment: in fact, i need to `sum` all observations for each field into last `TOTAL` line. i can't see same solution in this document, can you explain how to use report proc for my problem?

Answer (score 3):

```
data one;
  set two end=eof ;
  /* do stuff */
  output ;
  if eof then do ;
    /* do extra row stuff */
    output ;
  end ;
run ;
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't know why the first answer talked about "totals". The correct way to update a table in-place is:

```
data newdata;
/* some code to generate your data */
proc append base=olddata data=newdata;
run;
```

This is much quicker than doing any modification that requires a scan of the dataset.

An interesting way to do the same thing is:

```
data newdata;
/* some code to generate your data */
data olddata;
modify olddata newdata;
by mykey;
run;
```

This does an update in-place without rewriting a large dataset. It uses the column key to identify matching rows and allows you to update rows without re-writing the dataset, appending those that are not found at the end.

Answer (score 1):

Just to add my thoughts, the solution offered by Chris J is a good one in that it only requires one pass if the data.  However, doing something like a proc summary and then appending the results to the end of the dataset is easier to code, it all comes down to how efficient each method is.  If you wanted to test Chris J's solution, then here is an example using the sashelp.class dataset.  This may well be the quickest solution for large datasets.

```
/* count number of numeric variables and assign to macro variable */
proc sql noprint;
select count(*) into :num_ct from dictionary.columns
where libname='SASHELP' and memname='CLASS' and type='num';
quit;

%put numeric variables = &num_ct.;

/* sum all numeric variables and output at the end as a TOTAL row */
data class;
set sashelp.class end=eof;
array numvar{&num_ct.} _numeric_;
array sumvar{&num_ct.} _temporary_;
do i=1 to &num_ct.;
    sumvar{i}+numvar{i};
end;
output;
if eof then do;
    call missing(of _all_);
    name='TOTAL';
    do i=1 to &num_ct.;
    numvar{i}=sumvar{i};
    end;
output;
end;
drop i;
run;
```

Comment: Another method to consider (if performance was super important) would be to summarise the data using your favorite summary technique, and then append the row using a data step with the `modify` statement to update the dataset in place.  This can save on massive amounts of I/O depending on the size of the dataset (and indexes).